# How to ignore Transformer formatting xml Java

Tags: java, xml, formatting

I'm modifying an xml file and I'm using the following code to export it. But I do not like how the Transformer is formatting my xml. Can I somehow keep the xml the way it was before ?

```
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    //transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(moduleFile);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: Does removing "transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");" help ?

Comment: No, that's just the indenting part. The transformer itself has some built in formatting, which I somehow want to disable, so my xml has the same formatting as he, before me modifying it, had.

Comment: Your _document_ object is just a Node, there is no formatting attached to that object. All the formatting is provided by the Transformer, so you will have to tell it which formatting you exactly need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much doubt that a DOM document has any "formatting", as it is an abstract representation of the XML *data*. The most that you can do is play with *some* whitespace, comments, and such. Some pointers.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace%28boolean%29

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringComments%28boolean%29